# Jenkins freestyle job configuration error: JSONObject["hudson-triggers-SCMTrigger"] is not a JSONObject

Tags: jenkins

Configuring jobs in Jenkins (v2.277.4 as well as at least two previous LTS releases) with SCM polling always yields the stack trace below.  This is the case for new jobs configured from scratch as well as when configuring long-existing jobs & saving with no changes.  SCMs being configured don't seem to matter either: jobs hooked up to TFVC and Git repos in TFS 2015 and in GitHub both yield the same results.  All of my internet searches have produced stuff that's near a decade old, so I'm at the end of my rope. Can anyone help?

```
JSONObject["hudson-triggers-SCMTrigger"] is not a JSONObject.

net.sf.json.JSONException: JSONObject["hudson-triggers-SCMTrigger"] is not a JSONObject.
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:2006)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.buildDescribable(AbstractProject.java:1815)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.submit(AbstractProject.java:1793)
    at hudson.model.Project.submit(Project.java:225)
    at hudson.model.Job.doConfigSubmit(Job.java:1335)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.doConfigSubmit(AbstractProject.java:768)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(Unknown Source)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:396)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:408)
    
    ...
    
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1036)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: We had the same problem. For those wondering, in our case this issue was introduced by the TFS plugin. We have deactivated it, which resolved our issue. My best guess would be, that this plugin is unmaintained since 2020 and was missing some important changes thus causing some sort of no longer supported compability mode.

Comment: @Taredon that has been my suspicion. Thank you. I've got just two of our projects remaining to move out of TFS before I can trash that plugin.

Comment: @Marian Thank you for this comment! This problem has been nagging our system for awhile, we didn't even have any TFS repos remaining that we were using. Disabled the plugin and now that error is gone!

Comment: Indeed.  @Marian if the mood strikes you, feel free to supply that comment as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @DanNarsavage Thanks for letting me know. Totally forgot about that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same problem. In our case this issue was introduced by the TFS plugin. Deactivating it resolved our issue. My best guess would be, that since this plugin is unmaintained since 2020 it is missing some important changes thus causing some sort of no longer supported compability mode.

This issue might give some more insight:
https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-64241