# After upgrading from Jenkins 2.384 to 2.426 I get "JSONObject["scm"] is not a JSONObject." when saving unchanged jobs

Tags: json, version-control

After upgrading from Jenkins 2.384 to 2.426 I get "JSONObject["scm"] is not a JSONObject."

I checked
["Jenkins freestyle job configuration error: JSONObject["hudson-triggers-SCMTrigger"] is not a JSONObject"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67425757/jenkins-freestyle-job-configuration-error-jsonobjecthudson-triggers-scmtrigge)-

In the article it is suggested to disable TFS and/or github-plugin.
But searching for TFS Team Foundation Server) Plug-in did not see that it is installed.

In many of my jobs i can remove the SCM-control but still thera are a few jobs left where it Used when a git repo is updated.

So where do I continue?

Answer (score 10):

As described in the [bug on the issue tracker](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-72202), the problem seems to be related to the [build timeout plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-timeout/). After we updated the plugin to its latest version (1.31) everything seems to be working.

Answer (score 5):

### Edit:
As mentioned by Bruno Bossola, updating the [Build Timeout Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-timeout/) to the newest version solved the issue for us.

The only fast solution we could come up with was to **downgrade back to version 2.409** which fixed the problem for us.

We had the Problem with our Jenkins Server after upgrading from Version 2.409 to 2.428

There is a recently posted Issue for this:
https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-72202

This only occured while trying to create or copy Maven-Jobs.
We also updated a bunch of Jenkins Plugins including GitLab Plugin, but the problem was still present.

Original exception:

```
net.sf.json.JSONException: JSONObject["scm"] is not a JSONObject.
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:2006)
    at hudson.scm.SCMS.parseSCM(SCMS.java:57)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.submit(AbstractProject.java:1833)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet.submit(MavenModuleSet.java:1209)
    at hudson.model.Job.doConfigSubmit(Job.java:1345)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.doConfigSubmit(AbstractProject.java:775)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:710)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:397)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:409)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:207)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.SelectionInterceptedFunction$Adapter.invoke(SelectionInterceptedFunction.java:36)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.verb.HttpVerbInterceptor.invoke(HttpVerbInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.SelectionInterceptedFunction.bindAndInvoke(SelectionInterceptedFunction.java:26)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:140)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:558)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:59)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:770)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:900)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:289)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:59)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:770)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:900)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:698)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:248)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1665)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.Endpoint$SSEListenChannelFilter.doFilter(Endpoint.java:248)
```

Comment: Reverted to Jenkins 2.402 from 2.429 and it's working fine now